# How to call a plugin or a script writting in python using Layer properties Action

Tags: plugins, action, layer, qgis

This is the first time I'm using QGIS. I have a layer and I don't know how to call a plugin wrote for QGIS or a script written in Python using Layer properties / Action.

Can I do it? And tell me the way to do it.

[image]

Comment: What you have done ?

Comment: Can you provide a minimalistic code,screenshot etc...?

Comment: Hi, Francisco. I've uploaded a screen capture. For example, I've had a script test.py. Can I run this program using action?

Comment: ckeck this ; https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/179078/python-script-for-opening-webpage-directly-in-qgis or https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60959/can-i-open-a-form-in-layer-action